# limiting JSON display values in API GET command

Tags: api, postman

Invoking an API call to my Aspera Shares server to get specific users:

https://myserver/api/v1/data/users/

Displays each user, with 40 lines of values. I'm only interested in 3 lines: "name", "id", and "last_accessed". Is there a way in Postman to display ONLY these values for each user? I tried using a simple Params:

https://myserver/api/v1/data/users?email=*@somecompany.com

https://myserver/api/v1/data/users?id=99

but it does not display select users, just all users. Am I doing something wrong..? or is Aspera super limited with API?

Comment: The API will always return all of the data they specify in the docs. You can get a single user with /api/v1/data/users/99, but only showing some of the fields would need to happen in your code after retrieving the data from their server (as far as I am aware).

Comment: Thanks, @BransonSmith. I guess my "confusion" is the fact that while testing here: https://api.stackexchange.com//2.3/users?fromdate=1639872000&todate=1639958400&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&user_id=17719350 it clearly allows for filtering, while the Aspera API apparently does not (scant docs indicate VERY BASIC functionality)

Comment: Also, FWIW, this works too: https://api.ibm.com/scinsights/run/api/events?_range=0-999

Answer (score 0):

Right,
the IBM Aspera Shares 1.x API is relatively limited:

https://developer.ibm.com/apis/catalog/aspera--aspera-shares-api/User%20Management

You can list all users, or a specific user by id. But all attributes are returned.

This is usually not an issue, as APIs are not meant to be used by humans but rather by software which can subsequently filter on needed attributes.

For example, if you get data by `curl` you can then filter using `jq`.

When using POSTMAN you can add a "test script":
https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/intro-to-scripts/

If you just want some command line tool, there is:

https://github.com/IBM/aspera-cli